can i pass back CMDs from a ssh terminal?
is that possible to "pass back" some commands from a ssh terminal to the local machine? i mean i have a local machine A, and i ssh from it to remote machine B, and the terminal/shell is on B, can i pass some cmds back to A.
i know it looks like a bit of unnecessary when i can fully access A, but i found it help to make some things more quick.
e.g.: when i navigated to some dir on B, if i can pass back the dir string(or more cmds) back to A, then i can start vscode on A more easily to remote connect to dir on B, it looks like more efficient just by cmds without operations of copy/paste/navigating dir for vscode gui on A.
